# Почему возвращает null?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

В условии задания нужно найти все совпадения цветов в шестнадцатеричной системе и вернуть их в массив, использовав RegExp.
Вот мой код, кто-то может сказать почему str.match возвращает null?

```
function getHexadecimalColors(str){
  const regExp = /^#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/gi;
  return str.match(regExp);
}
const testString = 'color: #3f3; background-color: #AA00ef; and: #abcd';
console.log(getHexadecimalColors(testString));
```

Answer (score 2):

Знаки `^` и `$` означают начало и конец строки, а у вас ни одно обозначение цвета не удовлетворяет требованию нахождения между началом и концом строки. Первый знак можно удалить, а второй заменить на `\b` — требование границы между словесными и несловесными символами.

```js
function getHexadecimalColors(str){
  const regExp = /#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}\b/gi;
  return str.match(regExp);
}
const testString = 'color: #3f3; background-color: #AA00ef; and: #abcd';
console.log(getHexadecimalColors(testString));
```